# Eigen: What is the computational limitation for log()? (Windows vs. Linux)

Tags: c++, windows, eigen

I have a strange problem with my Eigen code. It works well on Linux (64 bit) and Mac OSX (64 bit), but it fails on Windows (32 bit) with an `1.#INF` value.

I traced down the problem to this function, where I implemented the Box-Muller-transform:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd box_muller ( const Eigen::VectorXd vRand )
{
    unsigned long n = vRand.rows();
    unsigned long m = n/2;

    Eigen::ArrayXd rand1 = vRand.head ( m );
    Eigen::ArrayXd rand2 = vRand.tail ( m );

    /* Implemented according to
     * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform
     */

    for ( unsigned long i=0; i<rand1.cols(); i++ )
    {
        if ( rand1 ( i ) < 1e-8 )
        {
            rand1 ( i ) = 1e-8;
        }
    }

    rand1 = (-2 * rand1.log()).sqrt(); // something must be wrong here

    std::cout << rand1.mean() << std::endl; // prints 1.#INF

    rand2 = rand2*2*M_PI;

    Eigen::MatrixXd result ( 2*m, 1 );
    Eigen::MatrixXd res1 = ( rand1 *rand2.cos() ).matrix();
    Eigen::MatrixXd res2 = ( rand1 *rand2.sin() ).matrix();
    result << res1, res2;

    return result;
}
```

This piece of code fails, but only on Windows and only for large input vectors vRand. It fails because in `rand1` there are unexpected values that generate `1.#INF`, `-1.#INF`, `1.#IND` or `1.#QNAN` values in subsequent computations. When I set the number of elements in `vRand` to a small number, say, `10000`, it works fine. But when the number is large (e.g. `100000`) it fails.

I tried everything I could think of and now I am out of ideas. What can I try to eliminate this problem?

More info:

- We're building this with MS Visual Studio 12.0. It runs on a buildserver, therefore I cannot find out the exact version easily.
- We are using C++0x, as far as I know.

Comment: Data, data, data. Which compiler, what version of the language, the statement which starts the `1.INF` train? did you try to debug this? You can even make the NaN a signalling NaN and not a quiet one.

Comment: Are you sure the values in `vRand` are all `<= e`, so that `log(x) <= 0.0` ?

Comment: You should save rand1 so you can find what values lead to the result

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint when a NAN or INF is generated?

Comment: @meneldal: Unfortunately, I cannot, since this only runs on a buildserver. I don't have a Windows machine. I cannot even save data, I just can print to the console which then will end up in the build log.

Comment: @PaulR: Good idea, I'll check that. It's just weird why this only ever happens on Windows and I wonder if there is a reason for that.

Comment: There may be a latent bug in the code that generates your input values which only shows up on Windows - see suggestions in answer below...

Comment: you could try to do the operation in two times (just the log first) and then with a loop check if some values are out of the range you are expecting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest replacing this loop:

```
for ( unsigned long i=0; i<rand1.cols(); i++ )
{
    if ( rand1 ( i ) < 1e-8 )
    {
        rand1 ( i ) = 1e-8;
    }
}
```

with:

```
rand1 = rand1.max(1e-8); // limit min value to 1e-8
rand1 = rand1.min(1.0);  // limit max value to 1.0
```

This would then guarantee that the values of `rand1.log()` will be `<= 0` and the subsequent `sqrt()` should not then fail. If this fixes the problem then you might want to work backwards to identify where the out-of-range input values are coming from.

Comment: Needs to be 1.0, not M_E

Comment: That was it! Thanks! I don't understand why, but this fixed it.